# What does SQL Server's SELECT col1=col2 mean in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I had a stored procedure in SQL Server which looked like this:

```
 ....
 Declare UserId VARCHAR(30);

 Select UserId=nrID
 from tblUsers
 where Email = in_email;
```

Does that `UserId = nrID` mean that the value of `nrID` from `tblUsers` gets passed to `UserId` where `email=in_email`?

If so, what is the equivalent in MySQL? Because it seems that MySQL is seeing "UserId=nrID" as a column name and not passing values.

Edit: Here is my full code

```
DELIMITER //
create procedure spResetPassword (IN in_email VARCHAR (100))
Begin
 Declare UserId VARCHAR(30);
 Declare GUID varchar(64);

 Select nrId as UserId #nrID is in the tblUsers
 from tblUsers
 where Email = in_email;

if (UserId IS NOT NULL) then
    Set GUID = UUID();

    Insert into tblResetPasswordRequests(ID, UserID, ResetRequestDateTime) Values(GUID, UserId, NOW());
    Select 1 as ReturnCode, GUID as UniqueId, in_email as Email;
else
    SELECT 0 as ReturnCode, NULL as UniqueId, NULL as Email;
end if;
end; //
DELIMITER ;
```

However, every time I `call spResetPassword('existingemail@gmail.com')` it always goes to the ELSE statement.

Comment: i think you don't declare variables in mysql

Comment: To answer the question in the title, in MySQL, `SELECT expr1=expr2` means MySQL will perform an equality comparison of the two expressions, and return TRUE, FALSE or NULL.  (TRUE will be returned as a value of 1, and FALSE is returned as a value of 0, and NULL returned as NULL.) To return an equivalent result from SQL Server, we could use something like this  `SELECT CASE WHEN expr1 = expr2 THEN 1 WHEN expr1 <> expr2 THEN 0 ELSE NULL END AS [expr1=expr2], ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a MySQL stored procedure, we can accomplish the equivalent with something like this, using the `SELECT ... INTO` to assign returned values into procedure variables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo(IN in_email VARCHAR(255))
AS 
BEGIN 

  DECLARE UserId VARCHAR(30);

  SELECT t.nrID
    FROM tblUsers t
   WHERE t.Email = in_email
   ORDER BY t.nrID 
   LIMIT 1
    INTO UserId ;
```

---

Variables can be declared in the context of a MySQL stored program. Those variables are "in scope" only within the enclosing block. Variables declared in a procedure are not available outside of the procedure.

MySQL also provides *user-defined variables*, which have names starting with an  at sign (`@`). User-defined variables can be referenced within a procedure, but they are not declared, and they scope within the entire session, not just the procedure.

Comment: I used the sign(@) at SQL Server procedures, but I saw that in MySQL they are mainly used for outputs from stored procedures. Anyway, I updated my post with the full code of the procedure, I don't know what's wrong?

Comment: Modify the SELECT statement to add an `INTO Userid` clause. It's not necessary to assign an alias to the column in the SELECT list. Because we are only going to get one value, we can add a `LIMIT 1` clause before the `INTO` clause, so the query will return at most one row.To make the result more determinant, we can add an `ORDER BY` clause before the `LIMIT` clause...      .

Comment: Also, i don't think we can reference the `UUID()` function in the context of a `SET` statement. But we can do this: `SELECT UUID() INTO Guid`

Comment: You just saved my life. I was not familiar with MySQL and spent hours on figuring out what's the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

in sql-server you do

```
declare @var varchar(30) 
select @var = fieldname from table
select @var
```

this will print @var value

in MySQL you don't declare variables just plain

```
select @var := fieldname from table
```

Comment: Hm? MySQL workbench recognizes DECLARE, and I just checked up the documentation, it says: DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements. (which in my case it's true(the other part of code i didnt show)) - However, by this new method that I learned, how do you set a datatype for them?

Comment: you cast the variable https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html

Comment: MySQL *user-defined variables* are not strongly typed. Only values of specific datatypes can be assigned to a user-defined variable. Procedure variables (variables declared in the context of a MySQL stored program) are declared as a specific datatype.   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html